# Set Multiple default values to a SqlDataSource Where Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a list view that is populated from SqlDataSource. It displays List of products from the database based on the Category value from the Query String. My categories in product table are `New|Fiction|Auto|Text`. How can i set a default value to display all the category.The category is selected from DropdownList. When i select ALL in the dropdownlist, I need to display all the product.

**Dropdownlist**

```
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddl" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectionChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
         <asp:ListItem Text="All" ></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Fiction" Value="~/Bio.aspx?Category=Fiction" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="TextBooks" Value="~/Bio.aspx?Category=Text" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Biography" Value="~/Bio.aspx?Category=Auto" />
         <asp:ListItem Text="New Release" Value="~/Bio.aspx?Category=New" />
    </asp:DropDownList>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:2016_675_z1787626ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Bio] WHERE ([Category] = @Category)" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Category" QueryStringField="Category" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify where clause in select statement.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddl" 
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectionChanged" 
   AutoPostBack="true">
   <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="~/Bio.aspx?Category=ALL" ></asp:ListItem>
   ...
</asp:DropDownList>

SELECT * FROM [Bio] WHERE (@Category = '' OR @Category = 'ALL' OR [Category] = @Category)
```